# Is this the correct architecture for a static class implementation?

Tags: c#

I have a static class which will hold various utilities, for the sake of simplifying, I've added Customers and Orders:

```
public static MyUtilityClass()
{
   public static readonly AnExpensiveObject ExpensiveObject = null; 
   public static Customers Customers;
   public static Orders Orders;

     static MyUtilityClass()
     {
        if (ExpensiveObject == null)
        { 
            ExpensiveObject = //Expensive operation
        }
     }   
}
```

In the above code, AnExpesiveObject ExpensiveObject is a property of the utility class that Customers and Orders will use.

Customers I've declared like this:

```
public class Customers
{
     public void SomeMethod()
     {
         var x = MyUtilityClass.ExpensiveObject; 
     }
}
```

The theory if what I am trying to do:

1. Create a static class that has sub classes as properties so I can write neat code like:

   `Utilities.Customers.GetCustomerById(50);`
2. Have these utility classes be able to access properties in the parent class, here since the parent class is static I'm just accessing it's properties directly without any inheritance model. Is this the right approach?
3. Also lastly Customers (The class) is coded non static, so do I have to create a new instance of it in MyUtilityClass() or because it is a static property of MyUtilityClass this is not needed?

Comment: You are holding mutable state inside a static utility class, this usually is a sign of a code smell. Why do you need all these properties inside a utility class?

Comment: @Kye - The majority of his points are from questions (and well received ones at that) so I would assume this is indeed his real account.

Comment: @Yuval, I don't have any mutable objects inside the static class. Once ExpensiveObject is set, it never changes (Just thought I would clarify that). Also the sub classes don't have properties, only methods.

Comment: @JL. `Orders` and `Customers` don't have any state? they're only utility methods?

Comment: @Yuval yeah they only hold utility methods. The idea is rather than have all the utility methods in 1 class, I've categorised them into sub classes. This makes it really convenient for reuse. You could do calls like Utility.Orders.GetAllActiveOrderIds(); (In reality I'm not working with orders or customers just for the example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works as I expected, and is easy to reuse, so I'll answer the question.

Answer (score 1):

At the risk of answering a question that is stated too broadly, I will give what I think is the correct, short answer: no, this is not the right way to do whatever it is you're trying to do.

Unfortunately, while you ask about inheritance, nothing in your code example shows any use of inheritance. So it's impossible to understand what you mean by that.

More problematic however, is the issue raised by your third point:

> 3. Also lastly Customers (The class) is coded non static, so do I have to create a new instance of it in MyUtilityClass() or because it is a static property of MyUtilityClass this is not needed?

The fact that you have to ask this question at all strongly suggests there's something fundamentally flawed with the design.

In particular, the question *I* would ask *you* is: what type of class is `Customers`? That is, does it make sense for your program to ever have more than one instance of it?

That question is an important one, as of the two possible answers, both lead to follow-up questions, both of which point to the proposed design as being wrong:

1. Possible answer #1: "no, there will only ever be one `Customers` object at a time". In that case, it makes more sense to implement the class as a singleton, which means the accessor should be e.g. an `Instance` property in the `Customers` class itself, not something in a separate "utility" class.
2. Possible answer #2: "yes, there can be multiple instances of the `Customers` object during the execution of this program". In that case, the question is raised as to *which* instance becomes the "special" instance in your "utilities" class and why? Furthermore, could there be more than one instance that would hold that special status? Why, or why not?

Hopefully it's the first answer above that is correct, in which case the path is clear: use the singleton pattern rather than this catch-all "utility" class.

If it's the second answer above that is correct, then I can say with reasonable confidence your proposed design is incorrect. Unfortunately, to say what design *would* be correct would be much harder, and would require far more detail from you, making the question itself far too broad for StackOverflow.